# C++ struct in a class with error: expected an identifier

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Here is the simplest I think I can get this code:

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size);

private:
    struct controlChoice
    {
        wxChoice *choice;
        int prevChoice;
    };
    wxPanel *panel;
    controlChoice *profileChoice;

}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    this->panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    controlChoice this->profileChoice;
    this->profileChoice->choice = new wxChoice(this->panel, wxID_ANY);
}
```

On the line **"controlChoice this->profileChoice;"**
I receive **"error: expected an identifier"** and it's the "this" that's showing the error.

*EDIT: removed the "does compile". Possibly it wasn't removing the previously successfully compiled executable and I just kept loading that.*

Comment: It's unlikely this code compile, actually. `controlChoice this->profileChoice` is not valid C++. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Explain in your own words what the line `controlChoice this->profileChoice;` should do. That's a typename followed by a `this`-quantified field, which is not valid C++ syntax.

Comment: Can you explain why you need the `this->` syntax?  I've written dozens of C++ programs and never used the `this->` syntax.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The only place `this` is needed in the given program is when writing `new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY)`, everywhere else(in the shown sample) it is optional. But `this->` is not needed. Maybe OP wanted to be explicit. But then they ended up writing incorrect code like `controlChoice this->profileChoice;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code does compile.

That is not valid C++ syntax and any conformant C++ compiler should reject it as `controlChoice` is a `typename` while `this->profileChoice` is a **qualified name** and C++ grammar rules doesn't allow such an usage.

---

You can instead use the **member initializer list** for initialization of those members:

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size);

private:
    struct controlChoice
    {
        wxChoice *choice;
        int prevChoice;
        //add a constructor
        controlChoice(wxChoice *pChoice, int pPrevChoice): choice(pChoice), 
                                                           prevChoice(pPrevChoice)
    {
    }
    };
    wxPanel *panel;
    controlChoice *profileChoice;

}
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size), 
      panel(new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY)),
      profileChoice(new controlChoice(new wxChoice(this->panel, wxID_ANY), 5))
{
    
    //empty body as we did the initialization in the member initializer list
    
}
```

Note that **initialization** can be done in the member initializaer as opposed to **assignment** which is done in the constructor body. And since in the modified program we've used the member initializer list, we don't need to do anything else in the constructor body.

Comment: Thank you for the response. On the profileChoice example you provided, I'm getting "a value of type "wxChoice *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "MyFrame::controlChoice *" ... It needs to be profileChoice.choice(new...) right? But the proFileChoice would have to be initialized first?

Comment: @Chemdream You're welcome. Actually you need to add a constructor to your class `controlChoice` so that you can initialize `profileChoice`. I will update the answer to show that in a minute.

Comment: Ah. I'm coming from Golang. That might be confusing me. Because I controlChoice is a struct. That's why I thought I'd initialize it in the MyFrame::MyFrame. I didn't realize structs needed a constructor.

Comment: @Chemdream I've updated the answer. Try the updated code. You can modify it according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks so much. Errors are already disappearing. I'll school myself in struct constructors and check this one as the answer. Sincerely, thank you again!